# Not receiving any data from webpage to content.js of chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send a message from a button click even on my website which is opened in a tab by chrome extension.

But, I'm not able to get any message from the webpage and I get a port error.

My content.js:

```
var port = chrome.extension.connect();

port.onMessage.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    // We only accept messages from ourselves
    if (event.source != window)
      return;

    if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "FROM_PAGE")) {
      console.log("Content script received: " + event.data.text);
      port.postMessage(event.data.text);
    }
}, false);


chrome.tabs.onMessage.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  alert(changeInfo);
});
```

Popup.js

```
    $("#linkify").click(function() {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            'url': 'http://localhost:3000/signin'
        }, function(tab) {
            // Tab opened.
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                file: "jquery.js"
            }, function() {
                console.log('all injected');
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                    file: "content.js"
                }, function() {
                    console.log('all injected');
                    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, function() {
                        console.log('all injected');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        //getlink();
    });
});


function checkUserAuth() {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("apiKey"));
    if (localStorage.getItem("apiKey") != null) {
        document.getElementById('openBackgroundWindow').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}

var port = chrome.extension.connect({
    name: "Sample Communication"
});
port.postMessage("Hi BackGround");
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    console.log("message recieved" + msg);
});
```

My background.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");

  });
```

Script that sends message from the web url:

```
document.getElementById("theButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("message being sent");
    window.postMessage({ type: "FROM_PAGE", text: "Hello from the webpage!" }, "*");
}, false);
```

Where am I going wrong here that I am not receiving any message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After making some changes to your scripts i got it running **:)**

This question covers message passing from `extension page -- > background`, `content page -- > background`, `extension page --> content page`

**Output from destination page** (In my case it is `http://www.google.co.in/` for you it is `http://localhost:3000/signin`)

[image]

***Output from popup.js***

[image]

***Output from background.js***

[image]

I have added a connection listener for `var port = chrome.extension.connect({name: "Sample Communication"});` code in your popup.js in `background.js` it solved problem of `Receiving end do not exist`

***background.js***

```
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(content) {
        console.log("Connected ..." + content);
    });
});
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
        "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
        "from the extension");
});
```

Eliminated script injection right at the time of new tab creation and injected script after tab status is complete by looking for `tabs.onUpdated` Listener

***popup.js***

```
flag = false;
function customFunction() {
    chrome.tabs.create({
        'url': 'http://www.google.co.in/'
    }, function(tab) {
        flag = true;
        // Tab opened.
    });
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (flag) {
        if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
            console.log("Inject is called");
            injectScript(tab);
        }
    }
});

function injectScript(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        file: "jquery.js",
        "runAt": "document_start"
    }, function() {
        console.log('all injected');
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            file: "content.js",
            "runAt": "document_start"
        }, function() {
            console.log('all injected');
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, function() {
                console.log('all injected');
            });
        });
    });
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("linkify").onclick = customFunction;
};

var port = chrome.extension.connect({
    name: "Sample Communication"
});
port.postMessage("Hi BackGround");
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    console.log("message recieved" + msg);
});
```

Eliminated `window.postMessage()` from web page and injected a custom script to send message to popup.js on click of button(Here i have chosen google logo)

***content.js***

```
function bindFunction() {
    console.log("message being sent");
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({ type: "FROM_PAGE", text: "Hello from the webpage!" });
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("hplogo").onclick = bindFunction;
};
```

Sample Page where `linkify` button is similar to login button

***popup.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="linkify">Linkify</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Ensured all code has permissions in `manifest.json` for injected script files,tabs etc in a complete `manifest.json` file

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "name": "Complex Calls",
  "description": "Complex Calls Demo",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "screen.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "version": "1"
}
```

Comment: There's a proverb which says that if you give one a fish, he'll be fed for a day. Teach him to fish, and he'll be fed for a lifetime. In other words, presenting a wall of code helps the OP once, while an explanation will be extremely helpful to him (and others!). Could you explain why the OPs code failed, and what you did to fix it?

Comment: @RobW: I am wondering how beautiful now it looks after some explanation above each piece of code, thanks for providing suggestions and encouraging

Comment: The explanation makes the answer much better :) Instead of posting the lot of code (I've seen many of your answers), can you just answer the core problem? Having a full extension is a nice demonstration to the OP, but for others, it is quite difficult to find the solution in it. If you really want to post full extensions, go ahead, but please post a summary of the problem of the problem&solution at the top of the answer. (These are just some tips to make your answers even more awesome)

Comment: @RobW: Sure, i will definitely do that .. and thanks again for such cool suggestions :) ...