# Refused to connect to [url] because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I am the author of a Chrome extension that allows to translate status updates and comments right on Facebook: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-translate/plofenifjagmdikfcobngnfmmnfmphin

For some days now, my users and me are getting an error in the error console that sais:

> Refused to connect to 'https://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/Translate?appId=&text=Chrome-Integration%3A+Google+bringt+Google+Now+auf+Desktop-PCs&to=en&contentType=text%2Fhtml' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src https://*.facebook.com http://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net http://*.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.spotilocal.com:* https://*.akamaihd.net ws://*.facebook.com:* http://*.akamaihd.net".

In my chrome extension I did set the content security policy as follow:

> "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'"

The URIs in the error console, however, are FB URIs only so that's why I'm thinking Facebook did update their site to restrict access to remote URIs. I'm not certain if it could be a Chrome issue, so sorry if I started the topic on the wrong stackoverflow network. :)

Can anyone confirm (and maybe point me to a possible solution for) this issue? Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Extensions *should* bypass a page's Content Security Policy when executing XMLHTTPRequest from a content script. They currently aren't, which is a bug. I've filed https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104480 to take a look at fixing it.

Are you executing XHR from your extension's content script, or are you executing it in the background page? The latter should work right now.

Comment: Woah, thanks Mike! Indeed I am executing the XHR request from my extension's content script. Now that you mention it... I am doing all the OAuth stuff with the remote API in a background script, and the authentication seems to go through, so you're right.

Comment: The bug says it's fixed but I still see it. Anyone else still see it too?

Comment: It's fixed, but not yet in any stable channel. If you're seeing this behavior in Canary, I'd love a bug report. :)

Answer (score 1):

The error message says your are trying to connect to  'https://api.`microsofttranslator`.com/ domain which is not specified in [**connect-src**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/#policy-applies-to-a-wide-variety-of-resources) of CSP Directive

It seems you have listed

```
"connect-src 
            https://.facebook.com 
            http://.facebook.com 
            https://.fbcdn.net 
            http://.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net .spotilocal.com: 
            https://.akamaihd.net ws://.facebook.com:* 
            http://*.akamaihd.net".
```

the above domains for [**connect-src**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/#policy-applies-to-a-wide-variety-of-resources) policy, add the new domain `microsofttranslator`.com if it is valid.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: The thing is, I havn't listed these URIs anywhere in my Chrome extension manifest file (see my original post). That's why I think Facebook did add these content security directives. It's a new HTML5 technique and I think Facebook added these to their site to restrict AJAX requests to remote URIs, and I don't think I am able to overwrite them from my Chrome extension...

Comment: On a related note, that's what FB.com returns in their headers:
> X-WebKit-CSP:default-src *;script-src https://*.facebook.com http://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net http://*.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.google-analytics.com *.virtualearth.net *.google.com 127.0.0.1:* *.spotilocal.com:* chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.akamaihd.net http://*.akamaihd.net;style-src * 'unsafe-inline';connect-src https://*.facebook.com http://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net http://*.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.spotilocal.com:* https://*.;

Comment: @Alphawolf: i think with the headers it is clear that connection is only possible for  `https://*.facebook.com http://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net http://*.fbcdn.net .facebook.net *.spotilocal.com:` etc domains, so having `https://api.microsofttranslator.com/` not in the returned header list, it catched an error. Are you using `'https://api.microsofttranslator.com/` for translating?

Comment: Yep, I'm using the remote API at https://api.microsofttranslator.com to catch the translated string via AJAX. Until a few days ago it was working fine, so I guess Facebook added these CSP directives only lately.

Is there any way I can contact FB to include the api.microsofttranslator.com URI? Otherwise my extension is broken for good as it relies on the Translation API for my extension to work. Bummer.

Comment: @Alphawolf: I ain't sure of contacting FB etc and they responding immediately, can't you make an update for your extension with added URI's under permissions and CSP directive in manifest.json with this i feel at least new downloads work seamlessly.

Comment: Well, already tried that, but the `content_security_policy` directive in the manifest.json file does only apply to my extension, not to the website the extension gets injected. My extension does place "Translate" links below each status update on facebook.com which starts the AJAX request to `api.microsofttranslator.com` by clicking the link. As the AJAX request is getting invoked from facebook.com, I don't see any chance to get around FB's CSP directives. Not even by adding the URIs in my extension's manifest file...

Comment: @Alphawolf: Then place all the code in `background page` and pass content through message communication send content from `(content -> background)` for translating and `(background -> content)` after translating, you can check [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637715/not-receiving-any-data-from-webpage-to-content-js-of-chrome-extension/13638508#13638508) as a reference, it is the way to get this content script CSP tamed,let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score -1):

i had this problem out of the blue

paused ad-blocker on the domain, and now it works