# Cannot add data in google firestore with chrome extension background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-firestore

Getting this error while trying to add data from background.js file in chrome extension

> xhrio.js:632 Refused to connect to 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel?database=projects%2Fmind-map-data%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&VER=8&RID=60227&CVER=22&X-HTTP-Session-Id=gsessionid&%24httpHeaders=X-Goog-Api-Client%3Agl-js%2F%20fire%2F7.5.0%0D%0A&zx=i1wtdiez7b36&t=1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' wss://*.firebaseio.com".

The code for connection is:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "alksdnaksjsdf",
    authDomain: "asdasd.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://miasdlkamsd00sandata.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "asdkaskd-asdjads",
    storageBucket: "mind-map-data.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "840605340675",
    appId: "1:sadsadwes :web:2b3b13899ee06d9a4dea36",
    measurementId: "G-askdlamsdpo"
};

const app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
const appDb = firebase.firestore();


appDb.collection("mind-map-data").add({
    name: "dummy_map_1",
    timeStamp: (new Date()).getTime(),
    neurons: 3
}).then(() => {
    logConsoleInto(4, "data added successfully");
}).catch((err) => {
    logConsoleInto(4, err);
});
```

Comment: On this [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786918/refused-to-connect-to-url-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-p) they mentioned that extensions should bypass a page's Content Security Policy when executing XMLHTTPRequest from a content script. Also it might be worth giving it a try with the [workaround mentioned here](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/issues/175)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your `manifest.json`:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' wss://*.firebaseio.com;"
```

Comment: I tried by using this solution but it was still showing the error.

Answer (score 0):

> tl;dr: To improve security, cross-origin fetches will soon be disallowed from content scripts in Chrome Extensions.  Such requests can be made from extension background pages instead, and relayed to content scripts when needed.

Ref: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches